# Ansible webserver backup: pull other host vars to generate backup scripts

Tags: backup, ansible, jinja2

I'm using Ansible to manage a fleet of dissimilar cloud linux servers. I built a script that pulls backups down to a backup server via rync over ssh. All of the host vars are managed in `host_vars/example.com.yml` files, each containing the following:

```
ansible_host: example.com
ansible_user: user
ansible_port: 22
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_ed25519"
```

They are grouped in the `hosts` file like so:

```
[webservers]
example.com
foo.com
bar.com

[backup]
backupserver.domain.com
```

I have a backup role for the backup group containing the backupserver.domain.com server comprising the rsync scripts, but I have to manually replicate the ansible host_vars into that backup role to generate an SSH config containing all the information already in the `host_vars/*.yml` files.

So my question is, within a role is it possible to iterate through the host variables of another host outside of the current host and group? Something like:

```
{% for item in var_hosts_group %}
Host {{ item.ansible_host }}
   Hostname {{ item.ansible_host }}
   User {{ item.ansible_user }}
   Port {{ item.ansible_port }}
   IdentityFile {{ item.ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}

{% endfor %}
```

Then an rsync script would be:

```
{% for item in var_hosts_group %}
rsync -a {{ item.ansible_host }}:/remotebackup /localbackup
{% endfor %}
```

This would enable me to generate the necessary templates/scripts for the webservers on the backup server and keep everything nice and DRY. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Is it possible to iterate through the host variables of another host outside of the current host and groups?*"**

<sup>(I have changed `group/groups`. A host can be a member of multiple groups.)</sup>

A: Yes. It is possible. [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) is a dictionary of all hosts and their variables in the play, e.g

```yaml
{% for item in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
Host {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}
   Hostname {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}
   User {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_user'] }}
   Port {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_port'] }}
   IdentityFile {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_ssh_private_key_file'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

- Such a host must be a member of [ansible_play_hosts_all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). Quoting

> *"List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play"*

- If a host were not targeted by the play Ansible knows nothing about it, of course.
- You will very probably want to [`delegate_to` and `run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions) such a task.